# Are monsters with Sunlight Sensitivity supposed to have disadvantage when attacking or perceiving a target that is in direct sunlight?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, races, vision-and-light

Certain subterranean-dwelling monsters, such as drow and duergar, have the **Sunlight Sensitivity** trait, which is consistently worded as follows:

> While in sunlight, the [monster] has disadvantage on attack rolls, as well as on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight.

Of course, drow and duergar are also playable races for PCs. These playable races have an identically-named **Sunlight Sensitivity** trait, but its wording is different:

> You have disadvantage on attack rolls and on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight when you, **the target of your attack, or whatever you are trying to perceive** is in direct sunlight.

This is a significant difference. A drow PC attacking a target that stands in sunlight has disadvantage where a drow monster would not. One can imagine a drow PC traveling with a group of his monster drow kinsfolk and ending up the butt of jokes (or worse): "Poor Drew, for some reason he just can't hit the broad side of a barn when we're up on the surface. The rest of us, we just find some shade to snipe from and we're set. Even that doesn't seem to help Drew. I don't know what his problem is."

Am I missing something? Has this difference been either explained or errata'd somewhere?

Comment: What are you looking for here? It seems like you're asking for designer intent on way it is what it is. But you do seem to fully understand the two mechanics, so I'm not sure what the actual question is here.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to word this so as to avoid a designer-intent issue. My point is that the difference looks, to me, like an oversight that conceivably might have been corrected in errata. If that still runs afoul of the designer-intent rule, then we can close it.

Comment: I guess you could ask *if* there has been an errata, but that also seems pretty easy to check.

Comment: Interesting -- this question is getting close votes, but not all in the same category. Folks voting to close, can you offer some guidance?

Comment: I VTC'd opinion based since that's the default for designer reasons questions, which this is.

Comment: If you [join chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/trpg-general-chat), I've got an idea as to an answer though

Comment: Same as Thomas; I have an answer, but every time I wrote it out it always boiled down to designer intent